# Execute javascript on one page from another

Tags: javascript, browser

Providing my limitations are the abilities of the browser and I have two web pages, is it possible to write javascript on one that changes tabs and executes some javascript on another page?

Is there any way for two tabs to communicate to each other outside the server?

Comment: Do these pages have the same URL?

Comment: if these pages are on the same domain, and one opened the other (parent/child) then yes

Answer (score 2):

You can only do this if:

1. One tab opened the other.
2. Both pages are served from the same domain.

The opener tab just needs to store a reference to the window object returned from window.open(), and the new tab can reference the parent through window.opener.

Answer (score 1):

If HTML5 `SharedWorkers` is an option, I would suggest using those.

Pages that reference the same worker and have the right callbacks can update instantaneously, be they different pages or different tabs. As long as they're in the same browser, it'll work.

Here's a tutorial:

http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-shared-web-workers-html5/